# how to load content from another page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

**hi i am a new programer**
i want to replace the content of **current php page** from **another php page** using **ajax** without refreshing page.

the content to be replaced is in **div's**.

both pages (current and another) has same div's

**HTML Div's are:**

```
  <div class="category-container">
    <div class="category-image"></div>
    <div class="category-desc"><a href="#">#</a><p>text</p></div>
    <div class="rating5" >Editors' rating: </div>
    <div class="category-download-btn"><a href="#">Download</a></div>
    <div class="category-buy-btn"><a href="#">Buy</a></div>
  </div>
```

can anyone tell me how i can do it. it will be a great help.
also can you provide me ajax code not jquery.

thanks.

Comment: i have gone through many tutorials but didn't clearly get it that's why asking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery's [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), the section on loading page fragments:

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted.

To get the div content on another page into an analogous div on the current page, use something like:

```
$('#content').load('other-page.php #content');
// ^ target div                    ^ same div on the other page
```

Comment: this is the best way i found as i have to fetch only a portion from another page, thanks man u rock.

Comment: can you also tell me how to bring white color fading effect during page load (when getting data from another page).

Comment: Note, this will only work if the target page is on the same domain

Answer (score 2):

this is usual jquery.ajax call

```
function getVotes(id){
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'ay/templates/backend/_votes_partial.tpl.php',
    data: 'charity_id=' + id,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#shadow').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#popupContact').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#content').html(data);

    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way would be:

```
$.get("pageurl",function(data){
    $("yourdiv").html(data);
});
```

Comment: thank u, for php page i have to use $("yourdiv).php(data) will it work

Comment: nope. jQuery hasn't any php function. you can replace "pageurl" with the url of your php page, and "yourdiv" with the div content you want to change, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery.ajax its easy... old way of making ajax calls was too much complicated, jquery made it easy,

you need to install jquery library,include it in ur head tag and go thorough following link for clear understanding, its much easy

[Jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: i want to use ajax code it is smaller than jquery file that i have to link to. do you know any good tutorial for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in assuming jquery is the way to go.  I'm far from an expert, but this should help.  The docs are straightforward.

Generally, jQuery follows the *find something* then *do something* approach.

- Find something ---> watch for some action on some element (like changing a select box or clicking a link)
- Do something ---> make an ajax call to the php page you want replace the current div with the new div

The jQuery documentation is here with an example at the bottom that shows *exactly* what you're trying to do http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Some other helpful jQuery commands for this task could be...

- http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/
- http://api.jquery.com/remove/
- http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Hope this helps.